# Looking for an API or approach for range based parameter flight pricing using SabreCommandLLSRS

Tags: soap, sabre, sabredav

I need some insight into range parameter-based search using SabreAPI SabreCommandLLSRS. What I am trying to do is search the business-class pricing in the Sabre using API SabreCommandLLSRS between a given source and destination, and use the same destination as the new source (Let's say Source 2). I want to use Source 2 to find airports within a specific radius (let's say 500 km) and do a pricing query for all the airports within this radius.

Please review below the approach where the use of BB command has been made to fetch business class pricing between JFK to DEL. Now my goal is to use DEL as the new source and find all the flights waiting a range of 500 miles.

```
GDS Response for `128MARJFKDEL//BB`

1| 28MAR THU JFK/EDT DEL/9.5
2| 1AI 102 C9 D9 J0 Z0 JFKDEL 130P 1245P1 77W M 0 DCA /E
3| 2AA 292 C6 J6 R4 D6 I3 JFKDEL 830P 920P1 77W DB 0 DCA /E
4| 3EK 204 J6 C6 I6 O0 JFKDXB 1120A 750A1 388 M 0 DCA /E
5| 4EK 516 J6 C6 I6 O0 DEL 955A 240P 77W M 0 DCA /E
6| 5VS 26 J4 C4 D3 I3 Z0 JFKLHR 905A 755P 789 L 0 DCA /E
7| 6UK 18 C1 J1 D0 Z0 DEL 905P 1055A1 789 M 0 DCA /E.



GDS Response for `01D1*`

1| 1 AI 102D 28MAR Q JFKDEL SS1 130P 1245P 29MAR F /DCAI /E
2| NAME CHG NOT ALLOWED FOR AI-D FARECLASS.



GDS Response for `*R`

1| NO NAMES
2| 1 AI 102D 28MAR Q JFKDEL SS1 130P 1245P 29MAR F /DCAI /E
3| E3CK.E3CK*AWS 0619/26MAR24



GDS Response for `WP`

1| 28MAR DEPARTURE DATE-----LAST DAY TO PURCHASE 28MAR/0900
2| BASE FARE TAXES/FEES/CHARGES TOTAL
3| 1- USD3618.00 183.50XT USD3801.50ADT
4| XT 150.00YQ 1.20YR 22.20US 5.60AY
5| 4.50XF
6| 3618.00 183.50 3801.50TTL
7| ADT-01 DLSO3JFF
8| NYC AI DEL Q20.00 3598.00NUC3618.00END ROE1.00 XFJFK4.5
9| NON-END/CHANGE/CANCELLATION/NO-SHOW/PENALTY MAY APPLY AS
10| PER/FARE RULES
11| VALIDATING CARRIER - AI
12| CAT 15 SALES RESTRICTIONS FREE TEXT FOUND - VERIFY RULES
13| BAG ALLOWANCE -JFKDEL-02P/AI/EACH PIECE UP TO 70 POUNDS/32
14| KILOGRAMS AND UP TO 62 LINEAR INCHES/158 LINEAR CENTIMETERS
15| CARRY ON ALLOWANCE
16| JFKDEL-01P/12KG/AI
17| CARRY ON CHARGES
18| JFKDEL-AI-CARRY ON FEES UNKNOWN-CONTACT CARRIER
19| ADDITIONAL ALLOWANCES AND/OR DISCOUNTS MAY APPLY
20|
21| AIR EXTRAS AVAILABLE - SEE WP*AE
22| .
```